# Function within a loop (Python)

Tags: python-2.7

I am very new to this and only started looking at python this week.

I am currently trying to extract data from Google Analytics and need to extract multiple days of data. I am however having issues trying to loop the code for multiple days:

**CODE:**

```
for date in daterange( start, end ):
    # EXTRACT OVERALL VISITS AND UNIQUE VISITS;
        def get_results(service, profile_id):
            return service.data().ga().get(
                ids='ga:' + profile_id,
                start_date=str(date),
                end_date=str(date),
                metrics='ga:visits,ga:newVisits,ga:visitors').execute()
```

This however doesn't seem to loop, but give me the data for the last date defined.

Answer (score 3):

Your for loop is repeatedly defining a function, but never calling it.

Try this:

```
def get_results(service, profile_id, date):
    return service.data().ga().get(
            ids='ga:' + profile_id,
            start_date=str(date),
            end_date=str(date),
            metrics='ga:visits,ga:newVisits,ga:visitors').execute()

for date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
    get_results(service, profile_id, date)
```

Comment: I think I am calling the function later on here is the bit after:

Comment: Sorry if i am a bit slow on this one. It keeps saying Service not defined for the last line, when it is.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you about the "service not defined" error.  I don't have Google Analytics so I can't run this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
for date in daterange( start, end ):

    # EXTRACT OVERALL VISITS AND UNIQUE VISITS;
        def get_results(service, profile_id):
            return service.data().ga().get(
                ids='ga:' + profile_id,
                start_date=str(date),
                end_date=str(date),
                metrics='ga:visits,ga:newVisits,ga:visitors').execute()
    # EXTRACT UNIQUE PAGE VIEWS FOR IMPORTANT STAGES;

        def print_results(results):
            if results:
                # Print data nicely for the user.
                print (results)
                #print 'First Profile: %s' % results.get('profileInfo').get('profileName')
                #print 'Total Visits: %s' % results.get('rows')[0][0]
                #print 'Total New Visits: %s' % results.get('rows')[0][1]
                #print 'Total Unique Visitors: %s' % results.get('rows')[0][2]
                #print 'Unique Visitors Starting the Survey: %s' % results2.get('rows')[0][0]
                #print 'Unique Visitors Completing the Survey: %s' % results3.get('rows')[0][0]
                #print 'Unique Visitors Registering: %s' % results4.get('rows')[0][0]
                #print f

                # OUTPUT TO FILE.
               # f.write (str(date) + ',' + results.get('rows')[0][0] + ',' + results.get('rows')[0][2] + ',' + results2.get('rows')[0][0] + ',' + results3.get('rows')[0][0] + ',' + results4.get('rows')[0][0] + '\n')
                #f.close()
            else:
                print 'No results found'
```

Comment: Now, instead of repeatedly defining a function inside the `for` loop, this code repeatedly defines *two* functions.  This code doesn't call the functions; it just defines them.  I am confused as to why you posted this.

Comment: Yes maybe I am not including enough of the code for you to get what it is doing. Basically I have hacked (poorly) some code from google and trying to bend it to suit my needs. I will attach the whole code for your to see.